# Angular Kendo Grid to be Non-Scrollable, and allow height to fit the Row Contents?

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui, telerik, angular8

How do I make a Kendo Grid in Angular to be Non-Scrollable, and allow height to fit the row Contents?

This currently is not working, it gives me a fixed height still.

```
<kendo-grid [data]="propertyViews" [style.height.%]="100"
  [selectable]="false"
  [filterable]="false"
  scrollable="none"
  [sortable]="false"
  [pageable]="false"
  [loading]="loadingData">

<kendo-grid-column field="fullName" title="Full Name" [width]="80">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
        <div>{{dataItem.ownerCombinedname}}</div>
    </ng-template>      
</kendo-grid-column>
<kendo-grid-column field="address" title="Mailing Address" [width]="40">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
        <div>{{dataItem.address}}</div>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-kendo-grid?file=app/app.component.ts)

Two version of the gendo grid, one scrollable and the other not. You don't need to set any height to the grid.

What you need to do is check with what you have around the grid. Can you please provide a stackblitz example that reproduces the situation?